# Why does my program enters into an infinite loop when my char variable reaches the [del] character (127) value?

Tags: c++, while-loop, ascii, infinite-loop

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char x = 32;
    while (x <= 126) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
        x += 1;
    }
}
```

Until here, all goes right, but if I change my code to:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char x = 32;
    while (x <= 127 /* here the "bad" change */ ) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
        x += 1;
    }
}
```

to try to print the [del] character, **my program goes into an infinite loop** and starts to print a lot of other characters which I don't want. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When x reach 127 it's flipped to -128 in the next round [-128 to 127]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Turn on your **warning options**!! (`-Wextra` for GCC)

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:41:15: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
   41 |     while ( x <= 127 )
      |             ~~^~~~~~
```

I guess the warning message is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 3):

Every value that fits into an 8-bit signed variable is less than or equal to 127. So if your platform uses 8-bit signed variables to hold characters, your loop will never exit.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all, I've replaced the char variable's type with an unsigned one and now the program works fine, here's my new  code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    unsigned char x = 0;
    while (x < 255) {
        x += 1;
        std::cout << short int(x) << ":\t" << x << "\n";
    }
}
```